# How can I implement a servletcontextlistener in my program?

Tags: java, servlets

Before I got to submit my assignment, the teacher told me that one of the requirements for the project was to use a servletcontextlistener. I read all about it but I don't have the practical skills to implement it. Can someone please explain how I can easily implement this method in my program, and it still be useful? Thank you.

The assignment was to build a website (frontend) and make a form (backend). Here is the servlet code, I don't think you need to see the HTML and the JavaScript.

```
      @WebServlet("/ServletProjekt")
      public class ServletProjekt extends HttpServlet{
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String firstName = request.getParameter("förnamn");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("efternamn");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String howoften = request.getParameter("howoften");
    String newsabout = request.getParameter("news");
    String[] age = request.getParameterValues("age");


    Cookie firstname = new Cookie ("firstname", firstName);
    Cookie lastname = new Cookie ("lastname", lastName);
    Cookie Address = new Cookie ("Address", address);
    Cookie mail = new Cookie ("mail", email);
    Cookie HowOften = new Cookie ("HowOften?", howoften);
    Cookie news = new Cookie ("news", newsabout);

    firstname.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
    lastname.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
    Address.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
    mail.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
    HowOften.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
    news.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);

    response.addCookie(firstname);
    response.addCookie(lastname);
    response.addCookie(Address);
    response.addCookie(mail);
    response.addCookie(HowOften);
    response.addCookie(news );



        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.write("<html>");
        printWriter.write("<h1> THANK YOU FOR YOUR INFORMATION</h1>");
        printWriter.write("<body>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your name:</p>" + firstName);
        printWriter.write("<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your last name:</p>" +lastName + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your address:</p>" +address + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your choice of often:</p>" +howoften + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your choice of news:</p>" +newsabout + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your email:</p>" +email + "<br>");

        for (String ages : age) {
            printWriter.write("<p>Your age:</p>" +ages + "<br>");
        }

        printWriter.write("<a href =\"GetAllCookies\">View All Cookies</a>");

        printWriter.write("</body>");
        printWriter.write("</html>");

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

implement following interface:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
```

and include the following in your web.xml(replace the class name with the correct one):

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.something.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Also with Servlet 3.0, you can use [annotation](http://blog.caucho.com/2009/10/06/servlet-30-tutorial-weblistener-webservlet-webfilter-and-webinitparam/) to implement listeners.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to create like this

```
public class yourServletContextListener 
           implements ServletContextListener{

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("ServletContextListener destroyed");
}

    //Run this before web application is started
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("ServletContextListener started");   
}
```

}

and write this in your web.xml

```
<listener>
<listener-class>
        fully qualified name for  yourServletContextListener 
    </listener-class>
```